# Error installing ckanclient on Python 3.3 using pip

Tags: python, pip, python-3.3, ckan

I'm trying to install ckanclient on Python 3.3 using pip. The command line I'm using is:

> c:\Python33\Scripts>pip install ckanclient

I'm getting:

```
Downloading/unpacking ckanclient
  Downloading ckanclient-0.10.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\lgms\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_lgms\ckanclient\setup.py) egg_info for package ckanclient
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "c:\users\lgms\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_lgms\ckanclient\setup.py"
, line 8, in <module>
        from ckanclient import __version__, __description__, __long_description_
_, __license__
      File ".\ckanclient\__init__.py", line 100
        except HTTPError, inst:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "c:\users\lgms\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_lgms\ckanclient\setup.py", li
ne 8, in <module>

    from ckanclient import __version__, __description__, __long_description__, _
_license__

  File ".\ckanclient\__init__.py", line 100

    except HTTPError, inst:

                    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

I need a clue about what is happening there and how to fix it. My OS is Windows 7 Pro, I'm using the standard Python distribution (I also have Anaconda Python installed, but this doesn't look like a version conflict).

The full error log is in: http://pastebin.com/NgFFCrcK

Answer (score 1):

ckanclient, as well as CKAN itself, is not compatible with Python 3. You'll need 2.7.

Another hint: ckanclient is deprecated, see https://github.com/okfn/ckanclient-deprecated. However, if for some reason you really need it please do not use the rather old pip (e.g. pypi) version, but the up-to-date one from github.